# mypy doesn't recognize the latest version of attrs?

Tags: python, mypy, python-attrs

Is some special setup needed to help `mypy` recognize standard `attrs` usage?

```
somefile.py:7: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "attr"  [import-not-found]
```

(followed by a bunch on errors due to mypy unable to understand the structure of the attrs class)

Here is the relavent output of `pip list`

```
attrs                      23.1.0
mypy                       1.7.1
mypy-extensions            1.0.0
types-attrs                19.1.0
typing_extensions          4.5.0
```

Comment: Are you sure that `mypy` and `pip` belong to the same interpreter?

Comment: Yes all in the same conda venv

Comment: Just to rule out environment issues, can you confirm that running mypy as `python3 -m mypy` produces the same error?

Comment: maybe use `python -m pip ...` instead of `pip ...` to make sure you install in correct Python

Comment: I can confirm that all libraries are in the same conda venv, I checked by running `pip list -vv` which shows the path of the installed lib. I see the same error when I run `python -m mypy ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyPy is shipping an attrs plugin and attrs ships it own type stubs forever. So, pretty sure it’s the `types-attrs` package that is confusing it (note, that the latest version is from 2019), try uninstalling it.